# python x86-64 installer on windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to install a 64-bit version of python on a windows 7 64-bit virtual machine. I got the Python 2.7.3 Windows X86-64 Installer from [here](http://www.python.org/getit). The installation worked straight forward but when I start python, I'm getting:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win 32
```

And if I try:

```
import sys
sys.maxint
2147483647
```

Which is not really what I would expect from a 64-bit python, and is different from what I get from my fedora 64 bit installation:

```
9223372036854775807
```

Any ideas ?

Regards,
Bogdan

Comment: I guess the difference is due to the fact that both python versions may have been compiled on different platforms.

Comment: But the msi installer is the Windows AMD64 / Intel 64 / X86-64 binary from python.org so how come it appears only to use 32-bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because [Windows 64-bit ABI is different from Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLP64#64-bit_data_models).

Python implementation uses C `long` type for Python `int` type and C `long` is still only 32-bit wide on a 64-bit Windows.

See `intobject.h` from Python:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    long ob_ival;
} PyIntObject;
```